# How to add event handler with Prototype new Element() constructor?

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

I'm inserting an img tag into my document with the new Element constructor like this (this works just fine):

```
$('placeholder').insert(new Element("img", {id:'something', src:myImage}))
```

I would like to trigger a function when this image loads, but I can't figure out the correct syntax. I'm guess it's something like this (which doesn't work).

```
$('placeholder').insert(new Element("img", 
    {id:'something', src:myImage, onload:function(){alert("MOO")}}))
```

I'm hoping to do this in the same line of code and not to have to attach an event observer separately.

**EDIT:** The event needs to be registered when the element is **created**, not after. If the image loads before the event is attached, the event will never fire.

Comment: Why don't you want two lines of code? Surely that would make things more clear/readable?

Comment: Because if you insert the image in the first line, by the time you get to the second one it is too late to attach the event because the image has already loaded. The event needs to be attached when the element is created, not after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the best solution is to not use Prototype or at least not exclusively. This works:

```
var img = new Element('img',{id:'logo',alt:'Hooray!'});
img.onload = function(){ alert(this.alt); };
img.src = 'logo.jpg';
```

The key is setting the onload directly instead of letting Prototype's wrapper do it for you, and set the src last (actually not sure about that, but I do it last to be safe).

One-liners are overrated. With proper use of local variables the above is just as good. If you must have a one-liner, create a wrapper function or hack the Prototype core to ensure proper assignment (submit a patch!).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('placeholder').insert(new Element("img", {
    id: 'something', 
    src:myImage
}).observe('load', function() {
    // onload code here
}));
```

Comment: That will not work because the observer is attached AFTER the element is created. The element loads before the event listener is working. The image would have to be pretty bit (I tested it) for this to work. Close though!

Answer (score 0):

You might have to move the function elsewhere and call it by name

```
$('placeholder').insert(new Element("img", 
    {id:'something', src:myImage, onload:"javascript:moo()"}))

function moo() {
    alert("MOO");
}
```

Of course, because `insert` returns the element, you could inline `Element.observe`

```
$('placeholder').insert(new Element("img", 
    {id:'something', src:myImage})).observe('load', function(){alert("MOO")});
```

Comment: Why would I need onload:"javascript:moo()", the only thing thing that can go into onload *IS* Javascript.

Comment: This actually will work (see my answer below for reasons why).  Don't downvote something until you try it.  The "javascript:" prefix is totally unnecessary, though.

Answer (score 0):

The "onload" code shouldn't need to be wrapped up into an event handler. You are essentially loading the element right there, just put the code after the insert.

```
var img = new Element('img', {id: 'something', src:'myImage.jpg'});
$('placeholder').insert(img);
// Element has loaded! It can now be mucked around with.
// The onload code goes here...
```

Answer (score 0):

It kind of sucks, but this is what you need to do:

```
$('placeholder').insert(new Element("img", {
    id:'something', src:myImage, onload:'alert("MOO")'
}));
```

---

The values in the attributes object just get inserted as strings, so when you do "onload: function() {...}" it turns into:

```
<img onload="function() {...}" />
```

Which doesn't actually execute the code inside the function, it just defines a new anonymous function that won't execute unless you tell it to.

---

If you wanted to be a ninja about it, you could do something like this:

```
var moo = function() { alert("MOO"); };
$('placeholder').insert(new Element("img", {
    id:'something', src:myImage, onload:'(' + moo + ')()'
}));
```

Or even:

```
$('placeholder').insert(new Element("img", {
    id:'something', src:myImage, onload:'(' + function() { alert("MOO"); } + ')()'
}));
```

While kind of crazy, those options give you the actual function object to work with in case you need it.

Comment: $('placeholder').insert(new Element("img", {
    id:'something', src:myImage, onload:'(' + function() { alert("MOO"); } + ')()'
})); -- this worked. Thanks!