# A way to override the constructor on HTMLElement so I can add custom code

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to somehow override the constructor of HTMLElement (specifically HTMLDivElement), so that whenever any are created by whatever means, I can run some custom logic.

Obviously this doesn't work:

`HTMLDivElement.prototype.constructor = function()
{
  alert('div created!');
}`

Is there a way to pull this off? Even if there was a way to get some sort of event/trigger when new elements where created (ones not part of the page's source HTML), that would be helpful.

EDIT: Maybe there is something we could do with Mozilla's watch/unwatch methods to watch for a change?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, but I would like to know how if it is.

Comment: Are you doing this for a specific browser?  Because ignoring your constructor issue - those DOM objects are exposed in IE, for example.

Comment: The constructor thing needs to work in Firefox 3.0 and lower as well as IE8. But right now I'm just trying to get Firefox going and will deal with IE8 later.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121831/javascript-universal-way-to-know-added-new-element

Comment: Do you have a specific reason, why you don't simply use a wrapper script? Like, 'I use third party apps, and their calls should be intercepted, too.' ...

Comment: The code isn't going to be used on our web site, it's going to be used on a multitude of different customers web sites, and we can't be certain what exactly they are doing with the DOM. It's one of those things that just has to work regardless of the situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I’m going to Hell for this:

```
document.createElement = (function (fn)
{
    return function (tagName)
    {
        var elem = fn.call(document, tagName);
        alert('just created a new ' + elem.tagName);
        return elem;
    };
})(document.createElement);
```

Comment: Nate...funny you would post that, it's what I had come up with after hacking around a bit...although I was too shy to post it :)

Comment: Of course, this won't work for elements created by dom parser (either upon loading page or setting innerHTML).

Answer (score 2):

If you could consider using jQuery there is a plugin called [Livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) which lets you trigger events on not yet created elements. So your example above could be written like this:

```
$("div").livequery('load', function(event) { 
    alert('div created!'); 
});
```

Note that I have not tried livequery myself, but I'm guessing since there are no answers to this question.

Hope it helps!

Comment: He was asking to *pure JavaScript*! Please don't use jQuery until he asks for it. Yes, DOM is ugly sometimes but jQuery is EVIL.

Comment: @m93a: I know that it's not what he specifically asked for, so I added that disclaimer in the beginning of the answer to clarify that. I also suggested looking at other answers. Also: it's from 2009, so I don't think jQuery was considered quite so evil in that pre-mobile world.

Comment: The vanilla approach would be [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) (that's what livequery uses).

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this is to use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using prototype.js, this answer may help.

> $('placeholder').insert(new Element("img", { id:'something', src:myImage, onload:'(' + function() { alert("MOO"); } + ')()' }));

- from [How to add event handler with Prototype new Element() constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278927/how-to-add-event-handler-with-prototype-new-element-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure you can make a 'hook' on every call of every new object in javascript...
but i'm quite sure you can make your own framework where everything will be catchable..
i recommend looking at:
http://code.google.com/p/joose-js/

or easy to go through article:
http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/03/18/javascript-metaclass-programming/

python has `__new__` and `__init__` as steps to construct the classes.. it would be good to check how javascript is dealing with the construction of new objects.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you controlling the changing/creation of said elements? Why can't you manually do whatever you want to after each element is created?